# How to Generate the M-Arithmetic Triangle - Java

Tags: java, pascals-triangle

I'm looking to generate an M-Arithmetic triangle of order 4. It's described here: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379509003577?np=y

And it looks like this:

```
1
1 1 1 1 
1 2 3 4 3 2 1
1 3 6 10 12 12 10 6 3 1 
1 4 10 20 31 40 44 40 31 20 10 4 1
```

And so on. The first two rows are always constant in my M-arithmetic triangle of order 4. From then on, each term is the sum of the term above it and the 3 terms on the left of the term above it.

The variables to define the size of the matrix which will contain these numbers are as follows

```
int y = user.nextInt();
int max = 3*y + 1;
int[][] m-arith = new int [y][max];
```

How do I generate the M-arithmetic triangle in code? As well as put zeroes into all the places not filled by numbers? I could declare the matrix manually like this (just gonna show a few rows):

```
int[][] m-arith = { 
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},                      
    };
```

But this seems like a monumental waste of time if I need anything more than a few rows.

Any ideas?

edit: For that matter, the code to generate an M-arithmetic triangle of any order would be interesting. However, am looking for solution specific to the order 4 triangle.

Comment: Why do you need to use a matrix to store your results?  Is this a requirement of the problem you have?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'll need the values to be used in further computation and a matrix seemed like the most convenient way to store and call. If you have neater ways to do it, I'm open. =)

Comment: But you only ever need the immediately preceding row.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You can do the same with 2D arrays in Java, as they don't have to be rectangular.

Comment: @TheveshTheva did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

> First, the default value of an integer in Java is zero. you don't have
>   to initialise those.

**Code:**

```
int y = user.nextInt();
int max = y*(y-1) + 1; // <--- updated here, change 3 with y-1
int[][] mat = new int [y+1][max]; // y+1 not y (for degree 4 we have 5 rows)

// ask user to enter the first two constant rows
mat [0][0] = user.nextInt();
for (int i=0;i<y;i++)
    mat [1][i] = user.nextInt();

for (int i=2;i<y+1;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<(y-1)*i+1;j++)
    {
        for (int k=j;k>=j-y+1;k--)
        {
            mat[i][j] += mat[i-1][k];
        }
    }
}

// print your array here!
```

Dynamic degree and dynamic constants

**Note:** as some pointed. 2D arrays in Java can be triangular.

Comment: You could also initialise each row to the correct size `i*3+1` rather than `max`.

Comment: sure but not i*3+1. its (y-1)*i+1

Comment: @hasan83 This solution works, but it depends upon the users entering the integers. Also, the number of rows should be y. I'm more looking to generate this entire thing in a similar manner to how you would a Pascal's triangle.

Comment: what do you mea it depends upon user entering the data? so what? its a dynamic degree solution. for sure the user will enter the data! for degree 4 which the logical thing to ask the user to enter as a value for y, the rows number must be/ should be 5 (y+1).

Comment: this solution exactly produces your output and solves the problem described in your question. nothing in the problem related to pascal's triangle. pascal's not mentioned in your question and doesn't affect it.

Comment: if you want you can ask another question about pascal's?!!

Comment: When the degree is 4 as described by your question we should have 5 rows. is that right?

Comment: @hasan83 Yup, I apologise. You're right about the number of rows being y + 1. The problems with having the user enter the values is that this code is to be implemented in an app. The user can't be expected to fill in parts of the code for me.

Comment: @hasan83 I wasn't looking to generate Pascal's triangle, but in the same way that the Pascal's triangle can be generated programmatically, I was wondering if M-arithmetic triangles could be generated in the same way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85359/discussion-between-thevesh-theva-and-hasan83).

Comment: Looks like it is where us the up vote and accepted answer. I dont see any.

Comment: Looks like that you can generate it